# Rewriting url with htaccess when a directory exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect a dynamic page to a dir, example:

```
url.com/index.php?page=download
to
url.com/download
```

The rule is very simple:

```
RewriteRule ^download$ /index.php?page=download
```

FULL .HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.url\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://url.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /index.php?page=download http://url.com/download
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^download$ /index.php?page=download
```

The problem is that I already have a directory named "download" and it's returning me a "403 Forbidden Error".
I have noticed that renaming the directory to anything different than the name (download) the rule is using will work.

So, my question is: how can I have my url rewritten the way I need and keep the directory?

**-- EDIT --**

My server, by default, protects every directory with a "403 Forbbiden Error". I believe this is the reason why it's not working, but I'm not sure.
Is it a conflict indeed?
What is happening?

Comment: Is that all the code? There is no reason for that error even if the directory existed.

Comment: @faa Yes, that's all the relevant code. So are you saying it should not happens?

Comment: Yes, the directory can even exist and still the rule should be used. It would be better if you update your question with the complete code, relevant or not. What about the options, are `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` or similar?

Comment: There is no "Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews or similar"

Comment: Well, insert that line on top of the rule-set. But it's all guessing unless you post the complete code.

Comment: I just added the rest of the htaccess so you can check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29276/discussion-between-darkeden-and-faa)

Comment: Let me get this straight. You're trying to map /download to index.php?page=download, right? Because if not, your rewrite rule is the wrong way around.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld yes, that's right, I'm trying to map to /download, so anyone can access my website on that way: url.com/download

Comment: Okay. Writing up an answer.

Comment: Sébastien, before you do it, please read the EDTIED section on my question (the last lines), thank you.

Comment: Your problem is the [L] flag in the penultimate rule, I think. I've put it as an answer as well as here.

Comment: Before I post this question I have tried to remove that entire rule as a test, but didn't work, so I don't think it can be the issue here...

Comment: Try removing the flag instead of finding excuses to not try something I've suggested? If the directory exists, the REDIRECT_STATUS will be set to 200 and not 404 (file exists), and the rewrite will run, and will stop due to it.

Comment: And just to add one more - if I am right, the reason you are getting a 403 is because it is trying to list the contents of /downloads/ . Do you have Indexes on or an index.php firing a 403? If not, you're getting a 403 due to that.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, maybe I have not left that clear before, but I really tried your suggestion - like anyone else here asking for help - inspite I had tried to remove the whole rule before. Concerning the "Indexes On" feature, I didn't think about that before and now I believe it can be the problem (or part of it). Also I don't have any "index"(php|html|etc) file on that dir.

Comment: So you have removed the [L] from the .* - rule (or removed that rule altogether) and it made no change?

Comment: As suggested by you, I have removed the [L] flag only. Before post the question I removed the whole rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/download/?page=download
```

The reason why this is happening is because somewhere mod_dir redirects all requests for directories that are missing the trailing slash to include the trailing slash. This is interferring with your rewrite rule. Since your server is automatically setup to deny listing of directories, it's probably safe to go ahead and turn directory slashes off:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Answer by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/851273/jon-lin

Comment: That's good to know. So it was a module conflict... The question is: how could anyone have guessed that from your question?

Comment: Jon Lin did... you can check it right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346691/rewrite-rule-leads-to-403-forbbiden-error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, I think, due to this specific rewrite rule:

```
 RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Apache will read your htaccess in detail, line by line, and will try to map each rewrite rule in turn (+ conditions, obviously). Let's follow it in detail.

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.url\.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://url.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

These two by themselves are **NOT** fine but not the source of your problem. If the HTTP HOST is anything but www.url.com, it will redirect to http://url.com/... which is not www.url.com, which will then redirect to url.com. You have a potential infinite loop but only if the HTTP HOST is not www.url.com to start with. If it matched, due to the L flag, it breaks processing and returns the redirect.

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?page=download http://url.com/download
```

This line is fine. You're doing a 301 redirect to anyone who happens to know index.php?page=download.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

This line is **NOT** fine. The rewrite condition specifies that, so far, anything that is not a redirect from above will work for the next rule. The next rule matches **EVERYTHING** (.* means everything. 0 or more characters of anything) and in-rewrites to -, which in mod_rewrite language is a do not touch flag. This is fine. However, **the L flag breaks the chain and returns**, which causes your download/ folder to show as the list of your actual download folder, which is the source of your 403 error.

Remove the L flag to get the next rule to process:

```
RewriteRule ^download$ /index.php?page=download
```

Which is fine by itself.

Comment: As I answered before on the question comments, I have tried to remove all previous rules as test before posting this question and it didn't work.