# Rewrite rule leads to 403 forbbiden error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have asked a question here yesterday and user "faa" tried to help me, but unfortunately we couldn't solve the issue.

Original question is here: [Rewriting url with htaccess when a directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328894)

I am doing a simple rewrite but it is not working (apparently) due to directory access permissions.

**The Code:**

*Dynamic Page: url.com/index.php?page=download

Rewrite Rule: ^download$ /index.php?page=download

**The problem:**

A directory named "download" exists.
When the rewrite rule tries rewrite the Dynamic Page* to the path "download", it returns a 403 FORBBIDEN error and the page gets rewritten to "download/?page=download".

Now, if I rename that directory to something else, like "downloads", then it works.

**-- EDIT --**

My server, by default, protects every directory with a "403 Forbbiden Error". I believe this is the reason why it's not working, but I'm not sure.
Is it a conflict indeed?
What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /download/?page=download

The reason why this is happening is because somewhere mod_dir redirects all requests for directories that are missing the trailing slash to include the trailing slash. This is interferring with your rewrite rule. Since your server is automatically setup to deny listing of directories, it's probably safe to go ahead and turn directory slashes off:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: that's simply AMAZING! Are you made of neurons? It was simply PERFECT! DA ANSWA! Thank you so much. Can you provide me more details about this issue? The idea behind it stills abstract for me

Comment: @Darkeden Nothing much to say, it's just 2 modules doing something to the request, and by the end of the URL-file mapping pipeline, you've rewritten the URI (mod_rewrite) and the request is flagged for a redirect (mod_dir), so you end up with some bizarre behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^download[/]?$ index.php?page=download
```

The rule matches even if the path was supplied with a /, so the directory *download* can't be accessed.

Make sure the RewriteRule executes even after a redirect.