# htaccess rewrite exposes real url when given existing directories

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1&artname=$2
```

When I try to access a directory structure that exists like: `/pics/vikings` the browser url is rewritten to `/pics/vikings/?name=pics&artname=vikings`. But this only happens if I do not include the last `/` to the url. So `/pics/vikings/` does not expose the real url.

I have tried adding rules for the existing directories like:

```
RewriteRule ^pics\/vikings/?$ /index.php
```

I have also tried adding `DirectorySlash Off` as suggested in [Rewriting url with htaccess when a directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328894/rewriting-url-with-htaccess-when-a-directory-exists)

Edit:
My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1&artname=$2

Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 /
ErrorDocument 404 /
ErrorDocument 405 /
ErrorDocument 500 /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude it if it's a directory
And just to be safe, also exclude if it's an existing file (optional).

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /index.php?name=$1&artname=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below line to your .htaccess code

```
Options -Indexes
```