# mod_rewrite tries to redirect if folder exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an HTTP-API, written in PHP and I redirect all calls to my index.php where a (Slim-)router does the rest. That works.

My redirection in `.htaccess` looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

There is only one problem: If one endpoint is named identically with an existing folder, strange things happen. That's the case when I create an endpoint `[PUT] /test`, while there is also a folder called `test`, containing unit tests.

This is what is happening:

- If I call `[PUT] /test` with preflight I get no response at all for the OPTIONS call which leads my app to fail. That's the real problem case, since I need CORS.
- If I call it without preflight and PUT I get 301 forwarding on the same endpoint.
- If I call it without preflight and POST I get 301 forwarding on the same endpoint, but with GET?!

**I guess I have to change something in `.htaccess` to make it ignore the existence of the folder, but what?**

***How to reproduce***

Have an Apache server and create directory as following:

- /target
- /target/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

- /target/index.php

```php
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

- /target/subfolder
- /testscript.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
        div {margin: 0.5em;}
        .error { background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);}
        .success { background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);}
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<script>
    const call = (url) => {

        fetch(url, {
            redirect: "manual",
            method: "POST"
        }).then(async response => {
            const className = (response.redirected) ? 'success' : 'error';
            const content = await response.text();
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += `<div class='${className}'>${url}<hr /><b>[${response.status}]</b> ${content}</div>`;
        });
    };

    call('target/endpoint');
    call('target/subfolder');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Open `http://localhost/`...`testscript.html` in browser and see: the call on `target/subfolder` changed it's method. Also when you look at network tab in browser console you can see, that there was 301 forwarding. Why? And more important: How can I circumvent this. **My desired behavior** is a rewrite without any changing in terms of method to the `index.php` in disregard of the existence of a folder with that name. In other words: The same what happens when I call `target/endpoint` for `target/subfolder`.

I know about `-d` (and `-f`) naturally, but that can be used - as far as I know - to to control behavior depending if file or folder exists - so I would assume without these flags the existence of the directory should not play any role, but it does, apparently.

Comment: Can you change to `call('target/subfolder/');` with a trailing slash and retest after clearing browser cache or with cache disabled.

Comment: So all problems solved?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean I can put a a hint in the API documentation that in this very special endpoint the trailing slash is crucial whereas it's never used at other endpoints. But that's not very consistent. Also I would love to understand what is happening here. Maybe you can elaborate a little bit? I would be to thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @anuhava I found the right way to solve this. His answer alone did not help, but led me to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328894/rewriting-url-with-htaccess-when-a-directory-exists), and I found out the solution war actually to disable automatic trailing slash in `.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

I had the additional (not mentioned before) requirement to define a exception directory which should be accessible directly. To make this possible as well, I needed the rule of @anuhava and I endet up with this `.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash Off

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

# rewrite all calls excpet for exception_dir to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/target/exception_dir
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

So first the reason of `301`:

1. You're requesting a URI `/target/subfolder` which actually points to an directory on your site.
2. Since your URI is missing a trailing slash. `mod_dir` module of Apache comes into action and sends a `301` redirect by making it `/target/subfolder/`. This is done for security reasons to avoid your directory content being exposed on the web.

To fix, you can just use `call` with a trailing slash everywhere it points to a directory:

```
call('target/subfolder/');
```

But this cumbersome because front end developers won't always know these specific cases.

You can use a generic rule in your .htaccess or Apache config to add this trailing slash:

```
# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure this rule is just below `RewriteEngine On` line and before your existing rules.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped a lot , although this was not the entire solution. For the sake of readability for the next visitor I write my own solution instead of marking your right, also I don't begrudge the points to you...

Comment: Just to let you know I am well aware of `DirectorySlash Off` but don't recommend it because of inherent security risks it brings. Please check this official doc: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash and carefully read **Security Warning**

Comment: Okay thank you! Unfortunately until now the `DirectorySlash Off` solution is the only one working.

Comment: Also in my case I have `Options -Indexes` anyway, so at least the exact case mentioned in the warning cannot happen (although some others maybe).